# Fragments Not Displaying After Switching To Different Fragment And Back

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager

I have an activity with three different fragments that are switched to via a bottom navigation view. The middle fragment, `TutorialFragment`, has a viewpager that switches between two other fragments.

The problem is that if I switch from `TutorialFragment` to a different fragment and then back to `TutorialFragment` via the bottom navigation view, the fragments inside `TutorialFragment`'s viewpager won't display.

Here's an example (notice how after I switch to "feedback" from "tutorial" and then back to "tutorial", the "Use Keyboard Fragment" and "Enable Keyboard Fragment" strings in the top right of the app no longer show):

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the code for `TutorialFragment`:

```
class TutorialFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var tutorialView : View

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        tutorialView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tutorial, container, false )
        tutorialView.tutorialViewPager.adapter = TutorialFragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager!!)
        tutorialView.circleIndicator.setViewPager(tutorialView.tutorialViewPager)
        return tutorialView
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be replacing

```
tutorialView.tutorialViewPager.adapter = TutorialFragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager!!)
```

with

```
tutorialView.tutorialViewPager.adapter = TutorialFragmentPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
```